# r- filtering table includes NA lines

Tags: r, matrix, filter, na

I need to filter a table:

Example table:

```
tabla<-data.frame( b=c(4,8, NA,4,12,8,NA), a=c(1))
```

If I filter with the following, I get:

```
> nrow(tabla[tabla$b<=7,])
[1] 4

> tabla[tabla$b<=7,]
      b  a
1     4  1
NA   NA NA
4     4  1
NA.1 NA NA
```

How can I exclude the NA in the matrix filtering??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated `is.na`

```
tabla[tabla$b <= 7 & !is.na(tabla$b), ]
#   b a
# 1 4 1
# 4 4 1
```

Another option is `na.omit`.  But beware that this will remove all rows containing an `NA` in any column.  So if you have `NA` in column `a`, but not in column `b`, that row will still be removed.  You may not want that here, but it's another good function to know for handling `NA` values.

```
na.omit(tabla)[na.omit(tabla)$b <= 7, ]
#   b a
# 1 4 1
# 4 4 1
```

Comment: this shouldn't be this way. na is not <=7 neither >7. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Which line are you referring to? In the first, `tabla$b <= 7 & !is.na(tabla$b)` basically says "the `b` column of `tabla` that is less than or equal to seven, and the `b` column of `tabla` is not `NA`".

Comment: your answer is ok, I'm saying the R filter shouldn't be like this.